# How to change caret color in a TRichMemo (Lazarus lcl)

Tags: lazarus, freepascal, caret

I am using the the [TRichMemo](http://wiki.freepascal.org/RichMemo#TRichMemo) with a dark color for the `Color` property. I can change the font color to white, but can't seem to find a way of changing the blinking caret color to something more striking (see screenshot. The caret is located between the 2 "l"s in Hello. Note the caret color is dark gray, but not white).

Is there a simple way of setting the caret color for a `TRichMemo`?
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Easy? Well sort of.

I had a similiar problem years ago and the answer I used then was a custom cursor.

This solution works in Delphi and should in theory work in Lazarus (but see http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=32861.0), but in any case maybe it will help you find your final solution.

The process in a nutshell is:

1) you need a cursor file, mycursor.cur. You may find one on the 'net, in delphi realm there was/is a utility that would allow you make one.

2) Make a text file like mycursor.rc (rc is uncompiled resource file).

3) In this example it will have one line: myCUR CURSOR "mycursor.cur", all these files should reside in the program's main folder.

4) This needs to be compiled to an .res (mycursor.res) file, see http://wiki.freepascal.org/Lazarus_Resources, in Delphi this file is/was brcc32.exe. The link above explains the process for lazarus, I have not tested it.

5) You then need to put a line in your code, main form is ok, like this:

{$R mycursor.res} delphi style;(precompiled resource file)

{$R mycursor.rc} lazarus style (it will/should be compiled for you). Almost done.

6) Now in formcreate put:

(Delphi:) screen.cursors[ 1 ] := loadcursor(hinstance,pchar('myCUR')); (use the name you gave it in the rc file. cursors idx 1 to 32000 are user definable, but here you will have to play around Lazarus handles it a bit differently, again see that link above).

7) Finally, assign the cursor to your control: Richedit1.Cursor := 1;

HTH.